# How to query based on particular property in firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

### these are my DB rules:

```
"rules": {
".read": "true",
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
},
```

### this is how my table looks like:

```
users
4BBlhgTyY3fD3jGYnV7SQavDasM2
     DateOfBirth: --
     Email: 
     Name: 
     PhoneNo: 
     Sex: 
     UserType: 
4zTTI5HajjNOlsfnzvQN9FoDshN2
     DateOfBirth: 
     Email: 
     Name: 
     PhoneNo: 
     Sex: 
     UserType:
```

I am trying to query and find nodes based on particular UserType, for example when UserType is "Child", but it's not giving me any result and the datasnapshot is null. what am I doing wrong? how can I solve it?

Comment: You're not granting read access to `/users`, so any listener that you attach to `/users` will be rejected. If you don't think that's the cause, edit your question to include the [minimal complete code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please don't include your answer in the question. Instead post it as an actual answer. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is what I changed and it works now:

Query query =   mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("UserType").equalTo(patient);

```
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot!=null) {
                Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("uid").child("Name")));
                int i=0;
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String userName = snapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                    Pt.add(userName);
              
                }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datasnapshot is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }

    });
```